# Insertar en BD variable PHP $_POST

Tags: php, post

tengo una duda/problema, quiero insertar en una tabla de mi base de datos un valor que es variable PHP, al pasarla por $_POST no me la guarda, existe otra manera de hacerlo?, les dejo el código, quizás me equivoqué en algo:

```
                $totalprice=0;  
                foreach($_SESSION['pedido'] as $id => $value) {

                $sql="SELECT * FROM producto WHERE Id IN (";$sql.=$id.",";$sql=substr($sql, 0, -1).") ORDER BY Tipo ASC";
                $query=mysqli_query($bd, $sql);

                while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query)){ 
                    $subtotal=$_SESSION['pedido'][$row['Id']]['quantity']*$row['Valor']; 

                    $totalprice+=$subtotal; 
                ?> 
                    <tr> 
                        <td><?php echo $row['Descripcion'] ?></td> 
                        <td><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Cantidad" name="quantity[<?php echo $row['Id'] ?>]" size="5" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['pedido'][$row['Id']]['quantity'] ?>" /></td> 
                        <td>$<?php echo $row['Valor'] ?></td> 
                        <td>$<?php echo $_SESSION['pedido'][$row['Id']]['quantity']*$row['Valor'] ?></td> 
                    </tr> 
                <?php 

                }

                } 

                //echo $sql;
                //exit;                     
               ?> 
        <div class="form-group">
                <tr>    
                    **<td colspan="4" name="total"><strong>Total:</strong> <?php echo $totalprice ?></td>**
                </tr> 
                </div>
```

PD: Lo que quiero guardar es el valor de $totalprice

Al pasarlo por $_POST debería lo estoy pasando así: 
$Total      = $_POST[$totalprice];

Está correcto?, favor sus respuestas.

Comment: a que te refieres al pasarla por POST? se puede recoger el valor de una variable que se pasa a traves de un metodo POST

Comment: Buenas noches, lo que pasa es que quiero almacenar el valor de esta variable: <?php echo $totalprice ?> (está casi en la última línea de mi código) en una tabla de mi BD, dicha variable es un total, entonces al guardarla en mi archivo controlador se supone que las variables por post serían: $variable = $_POST['name del objeto HTML'], pero en mi caso que tendría que poner? no sé si me explico?, saludos ;)

Comment: si pero tiene que haber un submit que te lleve esa variable al controlador

Comment: De hecho lo puse dentro de un form, pero aún así no me lo guarda, el tipo de dato le puse int:

Comment: $Total   = $_POST[$totalprice];
  $Mesa  = $_POST['Listamesa'];
  
  }
 
  //prepara la query
  $stmt = $bd->prepare("
  INSERT INTO pedido (Total) 
  VALUES (?)");
  
  
  //asigna las variables a la query
  $stmt->bind_param('i', $Total);
  
  //ejecuta la query
  $stmt->execute();

Answer (score 0):

Dices que la estas guardando como `$Total = $_POST[$totalprice];`
deberia ser asi `$Total = $_POST["total"];`. Recuerda que si lo envias por post debes recoger el name del elemento html

Comment: Probé esa opción pero no me lo guarda :/ seguiré intentando, cualquier sugerencia se agradece (Y) :)

Comment: Intenta con esto: ...**<td colspan="4" name="<?php echo $totalprice ?>"><strong>Total... y me dices

Comment: Intenté con lo que me dijiste compañero pero ni siquiera me sumaba el total, no funcionó :/ gracias de antemano.

Comment: Bien. En ese caso debes revisar paso a paso tu codigo y usar var_dump para ver cual es el dato que no estas recibiendo. Sospecho que es en la consulta. De nada de igual forma.

Comment: Bien, igual me estaba preguntando que quizás el problema sea porque esta variable está formada de la suma de un array + una variable, para ese caso su tipo int? o quizás sea otro tipo de dato? Al momento de insertarlo a la BD lo escribo así  $stmt->bind_param('i', $Total)

Comment: Alguna sugerencia? aún no puedo capturar los datos :(

Comment: Yo te aconsejaria hacer un echo o un var_dump de $totalprice antes y despues de la consulta y tambien cuando se este sumando con el subtotal para ver si se le esta asignando un valor.

Comment: OK, probaré y te aviso  :)

Comment: Solamente me sale que es un int, por ejemplo: al comienzo me sale: int(0) int(9000) int(14000)  y al final Total: $ int(14000)